# Apache radius authentication with backup local authentication

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04, pam, radius

I'm using PAM radius for Apache to restrict access to certain internal sites. The problem is that it only allows for one radius server. In the event this server was to go down, access would be denied. Is there a way to have Apache default to a local .htaccess file if it fails radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out myself, here's how I have it set up. Tries local then if fails, goes to RADIUS:

```
<Directory /var/www/test>
Require valid-user
Options Indexes Includes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secure Site"
AuthBasicProvider file radius

# Local Auth
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
AuthUserFile /var/www/test/.htpasswd

# RADIUS Auth
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
AuthRadiusAuthoritative on
AuthRadiusActive On
</Directory>
```